# How to Plot a transcendental function

Tags: plotting, special-functions

Let me try to be a bit schematic because my own expression is a bit complicated and could be not useful for future questions.

```
x=f[y*a[x]]
```

My problem is how to `Plot` `y=y[x]`. In principle, `y` is not a function but a parameter; but I need the curve `y` vs `x`

EDIT: Let me show you my functions

```
H=Sqrt[2α(1+2Sinh[Fk[α,k,H]]^2)-α^2-1]
```

with

```
Fk[α,k,H]=-(((1+Sqrt[1 + 4 k^2 (1+(-1+H^2+α^2)^2/(4 H^2))]) (EllipticK[1/2 (1+1/Sqrt[1+4 k^2 (1+(-1+H^2 +α^2)^2/(4 H^2))])]-EllipticPi[1/2-1/(2 Sqrt[1 + 4 k^2 (1+(-1+H^2 +α^2)^2/(4 H^2))]),1/2(1+1/Sqrt[1+4 k^2 (1+(-1+H^2 + α^2)^2/(4 H^2))])]))/(2(1+4 k^2 (1+(-1+H^2+α^2)^2/(4 H^2)))^(1/4) Abs[k Sqrt[1+(-1+H^2+α^2)^2/(4 H^2)]]))
```

Sorry, I know it looks horrible. Thus, what I want is a plot `k=k[H]`.

Comment: does the following example `ClearAll[a, f];
f[x_] := Sin[x];
a[x_] := x Cos[x];
ContourPlot[x == f[y a[x]], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, 0, 20}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]` give what you need?

Comment: @kglr Thanks. I'm running it now for my case but it is taking a lot of time. I edited my question to put my explicit example.

Comment: what is the correspondence between  `{H, \[Alpha], k}` and `{y,a,x,f}`?

Comment: @kglr you can fix `\[Alpha]` (sorry for not mention it), say `\[Alpha]`=0.8`, it is not a problem. The correspondence is `x=H`, the huge square root would be `f`, `a` the combination of elliptic integrals; and `y=k`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[k, H, f]
α = 4/5;
f[k_, H_] := -(((1 + Sqrt[1 + 4 k^2 (1 + (-1 + H^2 + α^2)^2/(4 H^2))]) 
 (EllipticK[1/2 (1 + 1/Sqrt[1 + 4 k^2 (1 + (-1 + H^2 + α^2)^2/(4 H^2))])] - 
  EllipticPi[1/2 - 1/(2 Sqrt[1 + 4 k^2 (1 + (-1 + H^2 + α^2)^2/(4 H^2))]), 
      1/2 (1 + 1/Sqrt[1 + 4 k^2 (1 + (-1 +  H^2 + α^2)^2/(4 H^2))])]))/
  (2 (1 + 4 k^2 (1 + (-1 + H^2 + α^2)^2/(4 H^2)))^(1/4) 
   Abs[k Sqrt[1 + (-1 + H^2 + α^2)^2/(4 H^2)]]));


Quiet @ ContourPlot[H == f[k, H], {H, 0, 1}, {k, -2, 2}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, FrameLabel -> {"H", "k"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had totally forgotten `ContourPlot`. I made a mistake when defined my functions, please check the correct definitions now. I was using `ContourPlot` in this case but it is taking infinite time. Is there a way to improve how `ContourPlot` works? Also, and didnt mention, sorry, that `k>0`

Comment: @resanrom, try (1) Clear all definitions using `ClearAll[H, Fk, h, \[Alpha], k]`, (2)  Use `Fk[\[Alpha]_, k_, H_] := ...`  when you define `Fk`, then (3) use `\[Alpha] = 3/4;
ContourPlot[
 Sqrt[2 \[Alpha] (1 + 2 Sinh[Fk[\[Alpha], k, H]]^2) - \[Alpha]^2 - 
    1] == Fk[\[Alpha], k, H], {H, 0, 1}, {k, -2, 2}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, FrameLabel -> {"H", "k"}]` It is still slow but it eliminates the recursion limit issue and gives some  output.